# decorator pattern with complex hierarchie: constructor causing core dump?

Tags: c++, oop, constructor, segmentation-fault, decorator

I try to implement a complex decorator in C++. Basically the important part of my code would look like this:

```
class Main {};
class Base : virtual public Main {};
class Deco : virtual public Main {
    Deco(Base* base);
};
class Sub : public Base, public Deco {
    Sub::Sub(Base* object) :
        Deco{object} {}
    Sub();
};
```

There are other classes like Sub, just with other names.
Now I want to be able to write something like this:

```
Main* object = new Sub1(new Sub2(new Sub1()));
```

I dont want to create a new Base in the inner scope, just Subs.
The following method will cause a segmentation fault:

```
Sub::Sub() :
    Deco{this} {}
```

I don't know, why this happens. Is there a way to fix this or avoid initializing Deco here?

Comment: Are you doing `delete` on that pointer? Are you copying/moving the `Sub` object?

Comment: i have to use `delete` somewhere, yes

Comment: I don't think there's *quite* enough code here for us to compile and see what's going on. You may not have shown the actual bug in your snippets.

Comment: Is it even possible to use `this` to initialize a base class in the way I do?

Comment: You can pass the pointer value, yes. The `Base` subobject should even be constructed by the time you pass it to the `Deco` constructor. However, since I can't see what you're _doing_ with the pointer, that's as far as I can go.

Comment: Thats exactly my problem: I can't do anything with the pointer. If i have a method `Sub::toString()` that simply outputs a string, I am not able to call `this->toString()` in `Sub::Sub()`.

Comment: The above code snippets don't show the problem and class `Sub` is not even valid C++ code. Can you please update the question with a minimal example that compiles and produces the segmentation fault?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer: It was a good example of the diamond problem. No way to fix that construct.

Had to replace the `Deco` class with a pointer in class `Base`.